# Sort a hash by key containing date in string format

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I have a hash containing date in string format as -

```
{Oct 2014: "some value", Aug 2012: "some value", July 2011: "new value"}
```

I want to sort them based on those. I tried calling sort_by or sort on keys, but since they are stored in string format, it sorts them alphabetically.

```
hash_name.keys.sort
```

This gives me in order of Aug 2012, July 2011, Oct 2014. While I'm trying to sort them in order of the year and month as --- July 2011, Aug 2012, Oct 2014

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) method to convert each *key* to a `Date` object :

```
require 'date'
hash = {
          'Oct 2014' => "some value", 
          'Aug 2012' => "some value", 
          'July 2011' => "new value"
       }
hash.sort_by { |k,_| Date.strptime(k,"%b %Y") }
# => [["July 2011", "new value"],
#     ["Aug 2012", "some value"],
#     ["Oct 2014", "some value"]]
```

Note :

- `%b` - The abbreviated month name (*'Jan'*)
- `%Y` - Year with century (can be negative, 4 digits at least) - *0001, 0000, 1995, 2009, 14292, etc.*

Comment: Thanks. This works for me. Is there a way that output shouldn't get converted to an array?

Comment: `sort_by` convert array, just do `Hash[hash.sort_by { |k,_| Date.strptime(k,"%b %Y") }]` to get the result as a hash.

Comment: I had the date in the format YYYY-MM-DD, so I used your method, I replated "%b %Y" with "%F".